# Non-static method AJAXChatFileSystem::getFileContents() should not be called statically

Tags: php, ajax, chat, non-static

I am setting up Ajax-Chat in my Apache Server (2.4) with PHP 7 but I am getting this error

> Deprecated: Non-static method AJAXChatFileSystem::getFileContents() should not be called statically in **C:\Apache24\htdocs\services\chat\lib\class\AJAXChatTemplate.php** on line 37

I tried changing `function getContent()` to `public static function getContent()` but after that it's showing:

> Fatal error:Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\Apache24\htdocs\services\chat\lib\class\AJAXChatTemplate.php:36

```
class AJAXChatTemplate {

    var $ajaxChat;
    var $_regExpTemplateTags;
    var $_templateFile;
    var $_contentType;
    var $_content;
    var $_parsedContent;

    // Constructor:
    function __construct(&$ajaxChat, $templateFile, $contentType=null) {
        $this->ajaxChat = $ajaxChat;
        $this->_regExpTemplateTags = '/\[(\w+?)(?:(?:\/)|(?:\](.+?)\[\/\1))\]/se';
        $this->_templateFile = $templateFile;
        $this->_contentType = $contentType;
    }

    function getParsedContent() {
        if(!$this->_parsedContent) {
            $this->parseContent();
        }
        return $this->_parsedContent;
    }

     function getContent() {
        if(!$this->_content) {
            $this->_content = AJAXChatFileSystem::getFileContents($this->_templateFile);
        }
        return $this->_content;
    }
}
```

Comment: Writing in all caps is considered screaming. Please don't scream at us.

Comment: Are you using the [AJAX-Chat](https://github.com/Frug/AJAX-Chat) library? If so, what version of this library are you using? It appears that in [previous versions](https://github.com/Frug/AJAX-Chat/issues/192) of this library, static methods were not called statically—this is now throws a deprecated warning since PHP 5.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling a non-static method statically in PHP is [deprecated behaviour  since version 7.0](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php#migration70.deprecated.static-calls) and raises an `E_DEPRECATED` warning. This means that support for this behavour works, but may (and probably will) be removed in a future version.

This behaviour raised an `E_STRICT` warning in PHP versions 5.*.

Changing your own `AJAXChatTemplate::getContent()` method to static does not work because it uses `$this` which only makes sense in the context of an instance of a class. Therefore it triggers a fatal error in a static context.

You are using the [AJAX-Chat](https://github.com/Frug/AJAX-Chat) library—you haven't stated what version you are using but there is an [issue](https://github.com/Frug/AJAX-Chat/issues/192) that discusses the error you encounterd.

In line with this reported issue, [a commit](https://github.com/Frug/AJAX-Chat/commit/ed891553d4f240dd19521b1656f6991f4327c591) to recent versions of this library were made to change this a static behaviour.

---

To resolve your issue, you have two choices:

**Continue to use the version of AJAX-Chat that you have currently installed**

Just use the `AJAXChatFileSystem::getFileContents()` non-statically. Create an instance of the class and use that by modifying your `getContent()` method like so:

```
function getContent()
{
    if (!$this->_content) {
        $ajaxChatFileSystem = new AJAXChatFileSystem(); 
        $this->_content = $ajaxChatFileSystem->getFileContents($this->_templateFile); 
    }

    return $this->_content;
}
```

**Upgrade to the latest version of this library and use the static method**

There does not appear to be a changelog, so you should  test your code wherever you use AJAX-Chat to ensure there are no breaking changes.

---

Technically, you have a third choice: since this is an `E_DEPRECATED` warning—implying that the functionality is flagged for removal at a future date—you can safely ignore this warning, *for now*.

`E_DEPRECATED` warnings (as with all notices, warnings and errors) should be disabled from display to the user in production code.

However, I do *not* recommend this because your logs will be full of `E_DEPRECATED` warnings. Moreover, as already mentioned, future versions of PHP may remove support for calling non-static methods statically.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: #Darragh Enright thanks for your reply but i  just start learning  codding just a week ago, so i don't know about php codding, can u tell me  how i use $ajaxChatFileSystem = new AJAXChatFileSystem();
$ajaxChatFileSystem->getFileContents($this->_templateFile); in   function getContent() {
        if(!$this->_content) {
            $this->_content = AJAXChatFileSystem::getFileContents($this->_templateFile);
        }
        return $this->_content;
    }
}      Beause i don't write this code i get this from sourceForge.com ....... This codes Are open Scource

Comment: thanks for your reply but i  just start learning  codding just a week ago, i don't know about php codding, can u tell me  how i use **$ajaxChatFileSystem = new AJAXChatFileSystem();
$ajaxChatFileSystem->getFileContents($this->_templateFile);**  in  **function getContent() {
        if(!$this->_content) {
            $this->_content = AJAXChatFileSystem::getFileContents($this->_templateFile);
        }
        return $this->_content;
    }
}**    Beause i don't write this code i get this from sourceForge.com ....... This codes Are open Scource

Comment: No problem @Rohit — I updated my answer to show how you would modify your `getContent()` method.

Comment: Here's a link to learn more about [OOP basics of PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php). Worth having a read.

Comment: **Thanks**, this problem is solved but i am getting to much errors  in installing this Ajax chat system because I am using latest version of php and codes of Ajax-chat is Written for older version of php .   **Can You Suggest me other good open source chat sytems.** I am using **Apache2.4, PHP 7 and Tomcat 7.0, and MySQL 5.7**

Comment: Glad to hear that the problem is solved. If you found this answer helpful you can upvote it and mark it as answered. With regard to the errors you have encountered—have you looked at the [latest version](https://github.com/Frug/AJAX-Chat/tree/master) of the AJAX Chat on GitHub and checked if it's a different version to the one you used. As I mentioend in my answers there was an update at some point to ensure static methods were not called statically.

Comment: Otherwise, I cannot recommend any specific open source chat system. I would search on GitHub, and perhaps consider looking at other languages (e.g: JavaScript), since PHP isn't really ideal for real-time chat out of the box.